# Divs not spanning vertically using CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to make a simple layout as I'm learning CSS Grid.

**The layout should be as follows:**
"header header header"
"adv content content"
"adv footer footer"

**What I'm getting is this:**
"header header header"
"adv content content"
".   footer footer"

The div "adv" never takes the vertical space, doesn't matter if I do it using template-areas as above or using grid-row and columns as the code below.
In fact, I'm not able to manipulate any of my divs vertically. I cannot make them span several rows. Can somebody maybe tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```css
body {
  background: dimgray;
}

div {
  height: 200px;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: floralwhite;
}

.header {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
}


/*Div having the issue below*/

.adv {
  background-color: blue;
  grid-row: 2/4;
  /*Expecting to span from row 2 to 4, but not happening.*/
}


/*Div having the issue above*/

.content {
  background: pink;
  grid-column: 2/4;
}

.footer {
  background-color: salmon;
  grid-column: 2/4;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">

    <div class="header">header
    </div>

    <div class="adv">adv
      <!--Div with the issue-->
    </div>

    <div class="content">content
    </div>

    <div class="footer">footer</div>



  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You should. [Take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your grid layout is fine, the problem is with: `div {height: 200}`, remove the height and it will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You forced the height of all divs to be the same. This of course means `adv` can't be as big as two divs. So try this, if you still need the a minimum height on all divs (or just remove hight all together):

```css
div {
      min-height: 200px; /* min/max-height is preferred to `height` for flexible layouts like grid and flex-box. */
      font-size: 50px;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      color: floralwhite;
    }
```

```css
body {
  background: dimgray;
}

div {
  min-height: 200px; /* height means that all divs will be the same hieght which prevents the layout you want. Min-height is more correct here. */
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: floralwhite;
}

.header {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
}


/*Div having the issue below*/

.adv {
  background-color: blue;
  grid-row: 2/4;
  /*Expecting to span from row 2 to 4, but not happening.*/
}


/*Div having the issue above*/

.content {
  background: pink;
  grid-column: 2/4;
}

.footer {
  background-color: salmon;
  grid-column: 2/4;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">

    <div class="header">header
    </div>

    <div class="adv">adv
      <!--Div with the issue-->
    </div>

    <div class="content">content
    </div>

    <div class="footer">footer</div>



  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
div.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: 'h h h' 'a c c' 'a f f';
}
.header { grid-area: h; }
```

...

templates columns and rows can only draw simples tables.

template-area permitt to customise the display.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: I don't think "templates columns and rows can only draw simples tables" is actually true. It does have limits, but it is possible to use it for the requested use case.